# How do you unit test an Async mehod

Tags: c#

I have some Async methods and some unit tests for them but they are very flaky. Is there a way to cleanly unit test such methods?

Answer (score 1):

Most test frameworks support async tests nowadays. Just mark your test methods as `async Task`.

xUnit:

```
[Fact]
public async Task AsyncTest()
{
    var result = await sut.OperationAsync();
    Assert.Equal(result, expected);
}
```

NUnit:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AsyncTest()
{
    var result = await sut.OperationAsync();
    Assert.Equal(result, expected);
}
```